# Unexpected exception using logstash file input - "exception"=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass>

Tags: logstash

I have a trouble using to process Fortimail log Files.

When I use the stdin input everything works without any problems . But when I use the file input I have an exception " undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass":

```
Exception in filterworker 
{"exception"=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass>,
"backtrace"=>["(ruby filter code):1:in `register'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in
`call'", "/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/filters/ruby.rb:38:in `filter'", "(eval):29:in
`initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'", 
"/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:262:in `filter'", 
"/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:203:in `filterworker'", 
"/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:143:in `start_filters'"], :level=>:error}
```

In the fortimail logs files, I have two type of logs (spam and statistics). Each type has its proper grok so I use the ruby filter to check the type of logs (with if statement)

```
ruby { 
  code => "event['type'] = event['message'].split('type=')[1].split(' ')[0]" 
} 
if [type] == "statistics" { 
   grok { grokparser -statistics } 
}
if [type] == "spam" { 
   grok { grokparser -spam } 
}
```

I feel that logstash not read the log file. 
the value of the Type field is empty

How I solve the problem now?

Comment: sorry but i can't see anything in you picture. Don't post screenshots.

Comment: it is true that it is not too clear in the pictures.

Comment: in the fortimail logs files, i have two type of logs (spam and statistics). Each type has its proper grok so i use the ruby filter to check the type of logs (with if statement) :

Comment: ruby {
                code => "event['type'] = event['message'].split('type=')[1].split(' ')[0]"
}

 if [type] == "statistics" {
  grok {
         grokparser -statistics  }
 }
 if [type] == "spam" {
  grok {
         grokparser -spam  }
 }
}

Comment: please post all in question body and use markup for formatting code, include all.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to go through the whole ruby thing.  Just change your config to something like this:

```
if [message] =~ "type=statistics" {
   grok { 
       // stats grok here
   }
} else if [message] =~ "type=spam" {
   grok { 
       // spam grok here
   }
}
```